# angularjs corousel stops working

Tags: angularjs, carousel

Im trying to make a carousel with ui-bootstrap for angularjs, i basically copied/pasted directly from the angular docs, and it works BUT it stops working at the last slide.

It does not come back to the beggining, and the controls stop working, im not getting any errors on the console, it simply stops working

```
<carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in carousel" active="slide.active">

        <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="app/assets/img/articles/{{slide.img}}" style="margin:auto;">

      </slide>
    </carousel>
```

EDIT: I have checked again And it does not stops working at the Last Slide, actually it stops at the SECOND, no matter how many elements there are.

EDIT: I made a test site just with the carousel and still is not working

This is the whole code, it stops at slide 2 and the controls stop working

```
<html >
<head>

    <title>Radiosan Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="app/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="app/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="app/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="app/assets/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="app/assets/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="app/assets/lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/RadiosanApp.js" ></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="RadiosanApp">

    <div class="container">

        <div ng-controller="MainController">
              <div style="height: 305px">
                <carousel interval="myInterval">
                  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </slide>
                </carousel>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
                  <br />Enter a negative number to stop the interval.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <script src="app/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
var app = 
angular.module(
    "RadiosanApp", [
    "ngRoute",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "ngAnimate",
    "RadiosanApp.Controllers.MainController"
    ]);

angular.module("RadiosanApp.Controllers.MainController", [])
    .controller("MainController", function($scope) {

      $scope.myInterval = 5000;
      var slides = $scope.slides = [];
      $scope.addSlide = function() {
        var newWidth = 600 + slides.length;
        slides.push({
          image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
          text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
            ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
        });
      };
      for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        $scope.addSlide();
      }


    });
```

Comment: the only thing that works are the small dots to chose a slide

Comment: Could you put it in a JS Fiddle?

Comment: My site and App are way too big for a fiddle... besides.. a small test in the fiddle it works fine :P .... and i'm basically copying and pasting, i really dont know why its stops

Comment: Im thinking maybe something is interfering with the carousel

Comment: I found out the Error, For some reason whenever I add ngAnimate together with the ui.bootstrap the carousel stops working, im not sure why, probabbly the libraries are not compatible, which is weird.... but I tried loading them in different order and still. No answer yet

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a compatibility problem between ui.bootstrap and ngAnimate .... https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1350

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem during many days, so thank you for answering this question

Comment: I've solved it by just using the carousel from the Boostsrap lib with a few of ngRepeats

Comment: The solution provided by simonykq on the link mentioned in the ans worked for me .. Thanks

Comment: hehehe... I was going crazy with this same problem! Thank you very much for asking and then answering your own question! @Bhumi Singhal: that solution was really a nice workaround. :)