# UI Bootstrap Carousel left/right arrows not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have this carousel using ui.bootstrap for angularJS. It is being put in a  and so far I have it looking right and the carousel indicators dots show up and work correctly letting me select whatever image I want. However, there are two arrows (one on each end letting you go back and forth), that when I click for the first time will work, but after that they don't do anything. Anyone know what is causing this?

```
<carousel>
  <slide ng-repeat="image in user.Contact.ImageUploads">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" class="image" style="height:200px; margin:auto">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this as well. ngAnimate and ui.bootstrap don't play nicely - you'll need to disable ngAnimate for the carousel. See related question here: [angularjs corousel stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641834/angularjs-corousel-stops-working)